# Cross farm / federated service application usage in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, web-services, user-profile-service

I know user profile service application is used in many company for cross farm / federated service application.

What other default service applications are also ***widely used*** in cross farm scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Search (& FAST) is the other main biggie. If you can farm out the Search to somewhere else on its own infrastructure you can have a really robust and fully featured search experience and it won't be (too) detrimental to farm performance, especially if you have multiple farms consuming it.